# How do I REConnect with GitHub..?

Tags: github

When I enter Cloud9, I can see workspaces.
And at the top of the right, there is a setting key(like saw-toothed wheel shape).
After click the button, I can see the "Connected Services" tab.
At the "Connected Services" tab, I saw 'Github' and 'Bitbucket'.
But, mistakenly, I clicked the disconnect button with GutHub.
And I don't know how to REconnect with Github...
Now, accidently, 2nd, 3rd ID were made. And In the 2nd, 3rd ID, there is no workspaces which I made in 1st ID...

I want to REconnect GitHub...

Answer (score 1):

The [Cloud9 documentation connected services](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://docs.c9.io/docs/connected-services) should explain how to associate/disassociate a GitHub (or bitBucket) account:

> 1. Head to [your settings page](https://c9.io/account/settings) and click Connected Services on the left side
> 2. Connect or disconnect GitHub and BitBucket as you please.
>
> **Note:** Sometimes users will sign up for an account and forget that they've never connected that account to GitHub. When they go to sign in, they think they can sign in with GitHub but that ends up making a new Cloud9 account.
>   If this occurs, sign out of your current account then sign in with whatever service you're trying to connect. At this point, you may be asked for an email address and you can just put in any email that's not already associated with a Cloud9 account (it can even be made up).
>   Now you'll just want to delete that second account completely.
>   Once you've done this, you can now log into your original Cloud9 account and run through the guide above to link your GitHub account to your desired Cloud9 account.

Comment: Thanks for comment~~!!
But, When I enter Cloud9, another ID is logged in automatically.
For example,  My original ID is "tesatmin".   
But, now, when I enter cloud9 page(www.c9.io/), tesatmin1 is logged in automatically...
Through c9.io/tesatmin, I can see my workspaces. But I can't open that workspaces. 
When I opened one workspace, cloud9 said ask for owner to access....
I can't solve this problem...

Comment: Can your delete that second account, as suggested by the doc?

Comment: yes, I typed my ID into delete blank, and I deleted.  BUt,, when I entered cloud9, new ID was made and I must type E-mail. I can't use my original ID's workspaces...
Um... do you know cloud9 contact mail ..? Maybe I inquire cloud9 service center...